# How to use Linux command Sort to sort the text file according to 4th column, numeric order?

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a file like this (which is space delimited):

```
AX-18 Chr1_419085 1 41908545 T C -1 98 0.51
AX-19 Chr1_419087 1 41908740 T C 0 15 0.067
AX-20 Chr1_419087 1 41908741 T C 0 13 0.067
```

and I want to use `sort` command to sort the file according to 4th column. I looked it up everywhere on internet and I find different solutions which nun works! I even find similar question in Stack Overflow which the answer didn't work for me! so these are the commands that I'm using and are not working!

```
sort -n -k 4,1 out1.txt
sort -n -k 4 out1.txt
sort -n -k4 out1.txt
sort -nk4 out1.txt
sort +4 out1.txt
```

so after running all these commands I get this output (which is identical to my input):

```
AX-18 Chr1_419085 1 41908545 T C -1 98 0.51
AX-19 Chr1_419087 1 41908740 T C 0 15 0.067
AX-20 Chr1_419087 1 41908741 T C 0 13 0.067
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
AX-19 Chr1_419087 1 41908741 T C 0 15 0.067
AX-20 Chr1_419087 1 41908740 T C 0 13 0.067
AX-18 Chr1_419085 1 41908545 T C -1 98 0.51
```

Comment: if you want more help, I suggest you specify what happens, and what you'd expect instead

Comment: 41908545 is less than 41908741. Do you want to sort the the numbers by their least significant digits?

Comment: Can you explain what rule causes your preferred ordering of `41908740`, `41908741`, `41908545`?  There appears to be **no** order to those.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
sort -nk4 file

-n for numerical sort
-k for providing key
```

or add `-r` option for reverse sorting

```
sort -nrk4 file
```

Answer (score 7):

`sort` does not sort the file in-place. It outputs a sorted copy instead.

You need `sort -n -k 4 out.txt > sorted-out.txt`.

**Edit:** To get the order you want you have to sort the file with the numbers *read in reverse*. This does it:

`cut -d' ' -f4 out.txt | rev | paste - out.txt | sort -k1 -n | cut -f2- > sorted-out.txt`

Comment: But your data doesn't have 41908745. It has 41908545.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
sort -k 4n out1.txt
```

Just tested this with GNU sort (--debug enabled):

```
$ tac input | /bin/sort --debug -k 4n
/bin/sort: using simple byte comparison
/bin/sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
AX-18 Chr1_419085 1 41908545 T C -1 98 0.51
                    ________
___________________________________________
AX-19 Chr1_419087 1 41908740 T C 0 15 0.067
                    ________
___________________________________________
AX-20 Chr1_419087 1 41908741 T C 0 13 0.067
                    ________
___________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to mention that if the words in each line of file are separated by delimiter except ‘space’, we can specify delimiter using “-t” option:

```
sort -n -t',' -k4 file -o outfile
```

We can get sorted output in any specified output file (using “-o” option) instead of displaying output on standard output.

source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/sort-files/