# sorting an output in numeric order bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a bash script that makes multiple API calls and prints out the specific data that i need.

it gets saved into a file called "result" and prints it out with the following command.

```
cat result | column -t -s "|"
```

which results in:

```
TYPE           CAPACITY  STATUS     LOCATION
0)ABC          13038G    Allocated  0:0:1 
1)ABC          13038G    Allocated  0:0:0 
2)DEF          13038G    Available  0:0:3 
3)ABC          13038G    Available  0:0:4 
4)GHI          13038G    Available  0:0:5 
5)DEF          13038G    Available  0:0:6 
6)DEF          13038G    Available  0:0:7 
7)ABC          13038G    Available  0:0:8 
8)GGI          13038G    Allocated  0:1:0 
9)BMD          13038G    Available  0:0:2 
10)BMW         1200G     Allocated  6:-1:-1 
11)MER        5588G     Available  0:1:7
```

- the `0) 1) 2) ... 11)` is added manually, its not part of the data.

The result comes out the way i want, but I want to make it better.

I want to somehow sort the data in a numeric order from the values in LOCATION.

so for example, it will be listed like this:

```
0:0:0
0:0:1
0:0:3
0:1:0
0:1:2
0:1:3
2:0:1
2:1:2
```

In a sense if its x:y:z

it will check z then y then x.

I've tried with the sort command but it just uses the 0) 1) 2) in the front which doesnt help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015533/how-to-use-linux-command-sort-to-sort-the-text-file-according-to-4th-column-num Please read `man sort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print;next } { split($4,map,":");map1[map[1]][map[2]][map[3]]=$0} END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for ( i in map1 ) { for ( j in map1[i]) { for ( k in map1[i][j]) { print map1[i][j][k] } } } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR==1 { 
             print;                                             # For the first line ( headers) print and skip to the next line
             next 
           } 
           { split($4,map,":");                                 # Split the fourth space separated field into the array map using ":" as the delimiter
             map1[map[1]][map[2]][map[3]]=$0                    # Create a 3 dimensional array called map with the first, second and third indexes of map as the indexes and the line as the value
           } 
       END { 
             PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";              # Set the array ordering (index number ascending)
             for ( i in map1 ) { 
               for ( j in map1[i]) { 
                  for ( k in map1[i][j]) { 
                    print map1[i][j][k]                          # At the end of processing the file, loop through the map1 array and print the values.
                  } 
                } 
              } 
             }' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. you are my hero