# How do i list files on ftp remote sorted by last added using cURL?

Tags: curl, ftp

For example i need to list files in folder on ftp remote sorted from older to newer

```
curl ls -ltc -u login:pass ftp://ip:port/path/to/file/
```

but ls -ltc didnt work. it listing sorted files from A to Z.
any ideas guys how to list files using curl and ftp? than you.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, `curl` cannot sort the FTP directory listing.

But [some FTP servers can sort the listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44666592/850848#44669601), usually using a proprietary switch to the `LIST` FTP command. If your FTP server can do that, you should be able to use [`-X`/`--request` switch](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) to tell `curl` what command to use. For example, if your FTP server understands the `-t` switch (ProFTPD, vsftpd):

```
curl -X "LIST -t" -u username:pass ftp://example.com/remote/path/
```

---

If your FTP server cannot do that, you will have to sort the listing from `curl` output locally. Something like this:
[How to use Linux command Sort to sort the text file according to 4th column, numeric order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9015533/850848)

Comment: thank u. but curl -X "LIST -t" not working. my sever based on windows server 2016 with filezilla server

Comment: FileZilla Server does not support the `-t` nor anything equivalent. See my updated answer.